# Cracks in my brick

Tags: windows, foundation, brick, cracks

I posted before that I have interior cracks in my house. Nail pops all over the house. And now I checked outside of my house I found cracks in the brick on the same side of the house.
House build in 1960 and I moved since 4 month only.

Does that mean all what is happening internally of cracks , nail pops dry walls looks like it’s splitting is foundation issue? Or settling or what is going on .

[[image: crack on left side next to basement window]]

[image: * second photo for crack under the Uber level window on the same side left *]

Some of the previous photos inside the house [image]

[! Wall looks like splitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8iCl.jpg) ][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8iCl.jpg)

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8iCl.jpg): [image: crawling space emphasized text]https://i.stack.imgur.com/QScux.jpg

Comment: Did you have the house inspected by a surveyor - they would usually notice serious issues especially useful before purchase.

Comment: We got inspection done before buying. I guess the crack on the brick is new

Comment: At time of inspection he mentioned few cracks in crawling space which we had fixed it recently as it was leaking.  Not sure do that have any relation with what’s happening in my house.

Answer (score 1):

The cracks in your photo of the bricks are probably from the foundation settling. There are many reasons for it to settle. Most are due to the surrounding earth getting removed or saturated (soft and compressed). Either leaves the concrete/block unsupported. Due to the immense weight of the structure that area settles away from the supported part.

I don't believe you are in imminent danger of your house collapsing. Especially from the findings and evaluation of the home inspector.

So for now it would be best to caulk the crack in the exterior brick to prevent water from getting inside. This repair also will enable you to accurately verify if there is any further movement in that if you see a crack along the repaired joint in the future than the structure is still moving.

Comment: It’s very disappointing as all this happened after we moved. Is this possible that fixing the cracks in my basement walls is the reason for the movement? As the guy fixed it from outside the house where he removed some blocks was placed on top of the crack. He removed it and replace it with some materials in the soils.

Answer (score 0):

Those cracks in the mortar and drywall don't look out of the ordinary and, while the photo of the crawl space is poor, nothing is obviously wrong there.

If in doubt, get a structural engineer to inspect the foundation and see if there is any movement that is going to compromise the structure.

Otherwise, just repair the damage and be done with it.

Comment: Any recommendations for good construction engineers I live in Illinois.

Comment: Not really, that's a local thing.  Try a search using your favorite search engine for "licensed structural engineer".